# glide not load image android imageview

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm new to glide so started with basic app with help of [this link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) but nothing get displayed in imageview.
**app gradle**

[image]

**activity**

[image]

[image]

**manifest**

[image]

Comment: can you post your xml code for Image view

Comment: Are you sure that it is giving you image? Try with another image url

Comment: I also tried with http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg

Comment: What is image resolution ? Try with this http://antonioleiva.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/kotlin_android_developers_cover.png

Comment: Don't post *images* post your *content*.

Comment: is it possible, there is some issue with **sdk** or **buildtool** or **supportv4** version I'm using

Comment: Check did u use internet permission or not? Your code is fine

Comment: Post your *manifest*.

Answer (score 3):

Did you include permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?